# Proof of First-Order Stochastic Dominance with Riemann Sums

Tags: utility, decision-theory

Let $A = \mathbb{R}$. For $p,q\in \mathcal{L}(A)$, $p$ first-order stochastically dominates (FOSD) $q$ if $F_p(a)-F_q(a) \leq 0, \forall a\in A$.

Show that $p$ first-order stochastically dominates $q$ if and only if for every non-decreasing function $v: A\to \mathbb{R}$,

$$
\sum_{a \in A} p(a) v(a) \geq \sum_{a \in A} q(a) v(a).
$$

Using Riemann sums instead of integrals made me life quite difficult for this proof. I am aware that $F_p(a)=\sum_{x\leq a}p(x)$. Maybe I should use expected values somewhere but I am really confused with this. I will appreciate any help at the moment.

Best

Comment: Consider also Mathematics Stack Exchange. Perhaps you will find a similar question already answered there.

Comment: The problem, it seems to me, is the meaning of a sum on a uncountanble set as in $\sum_{a \in A} q(a) v(a)$, if $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or an uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Have you a definition of this kind of sum?

Comment: By the way, why you write $A=\mathbb{R}$, instead of writing just $\mathbb{R}$ in the formulas? May be you meant $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @BakerStreet As far as I know, such a sum is usually defined for positive summands as the supremum of the sum over all finite subsets. For general summands, you can then split it into positive and negative parts.  Defined as such, it is equivalent to an integral with respect to the counting measure, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4664145/697506.

Not sure this helps, though.

Comment: @BakerStreet Also, to my knowledge it is not called a "Riemann sum", so maybe OP is referring to something else.  A clarification would be useful.

Comment: @  Wittgenstein's Poker Thank you for the answer. Yes, I knew this definition, but I'm not sure that the sum  can be finite for an uncountable set. I read about it in other posts on MathSE, where they  said  that a necessary condition for the sum to be finite is that the set is countable. But I'm not an expert of this, I was just asking.

Comment: @ Wittgenstein's PokerYes, I too was doubtful about the name 'Riemann sums', that for me is a different thing. I think that it could be clarified by the book the OP is referring to, there should be there these definitions.